# Converting time period strings to value/unit pair

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse the contents of a string that represents a time period. The format of the string is value/unit, e.g.: 1s, 60min, 24h. I would separate the actual value (an int) and unit (a str) to separated variables.

At the moment I do it like this:

```
def validate_time(time):
    binsize = time.strip()
    unit = re.sub('[0-9]','',binsize)
    if unit not in ['s','m','min','h','l']:
        print "Error: unit {0} is not valid".format(unit)
        sys.exit(2)
    tmp = re.sub('[^0-9]','',binsize)
    try:
        value = int(tmp)
    except ValueError:
        print "Error: {0} is not valid".format(time) 
        sys.exit(2)
    return value,unit
```

However, it is not ideal as things like 1m0 are also (wrongly) validated (`value=10`,`unit=m`).

What is the best way to validate/parse this input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply parse the whole line with one regular expression:

```
_timeunit = re.compile(r'^(?P<value>\d+)(?P<unit>s|m|min|h|l)$')
def validate_time(time):
    match = _timeunit.match(time.strip())
    if match is None:
        print "Error: {0} is not valid".format(time)
        sys.exit(2)

    return int(match.group('value')), match.group('unit')
```

Demo (with the sys.exit temporarily replaced with a return):

```
>>> validate_time('10l')
(10, 'l')
>>> validate_time('10l0')
Error: 10l0 is not valid
```

The regular expression matches digits at the start (matched by the `^` caret), then units from the limited set of `s`, `m`, `min`, `h` or `l`, but only if they are at the end of the line, matched by the `$` dollar sign.

It would be more pythonic to raise an exception in the validation method, btw, and handle that exception where you are calling the method. This makes it more reusable:

```
_timeunit = re.compile(r'^(?P<value>\d+)(?P<unit>s|m|min|h|l)$')
def validate_time(time):
    match = _timeunit.match(time.strip())
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError('{0} is not a valid timespan'.format(time))    
    return int(match.group('value')), match.group('unit')

try:
    validate_time(foobar)
except ValueError, e:
    print 'Error: {0}'.format(e.args[0])
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: I would include the whitespace at the beginning and end of the regular expression rather than using `strip` and also include optional whitespace between the value and unit. Also calling `exit` from a function is not cool, just raise an exception containing the error message.

Comment: I echoed the OP in using `sys.exit()`; I quite agree.

Answer (score 0):

Why not parse it in 1 go:

```
m = re.match(r'(?P<value>\d+)\s*(?P<unit>\w+)',time.strip())
#              #^number
#                            #^spaces (optional) 
#                               #^non-number
if not m:
   pass #error

if m.group(0) != time.strip():
   pass #error -- leftover stuff at the end.  This will catch '1m0'

unit = m.group('unit')
value = int(m.group('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

time = '1m'
try:
  m = re.match(r'^(?P<value>\d+)(?P<middle>.*)(?P<unit>(m|min|s|h|l))$',
    time.strip())
  value = m.group('value')
  unit = m.group('unit')
  middle = m.group('middle')
  if middle :
    # Reuse the exception raised if an expected group is not found
    raise AttributeError
  print value, unit
except AttributeError:
  print "Wrong format"
```

It ensures that the time starts with a digit and ends with a valid unit and catches anything in the middle.